# What kind of mean is this?

Tags: means

I recently came across the following method of calculating, from what I understand, a special kind of mean.

For 3 items: $\frac{\frac{a}{2} + b + \frac{c}{2}}{2}$

For 5 items: $\frac{\frac{a}{2} + b + c + d + \frac{e}{2}}{4}$

What kind of mean is this, and is there a general formula to calculate it? What is the advantage of using this mean over the normal one?

Comment: `What is the advantage of using this mean over the normal one?` That can't be answered without (a lot) more context about where you encountered these weighted means.

Comment: This sort of mean appears in [Trapezoidal rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule) for approximating an definite integral.

Answer (score 1):

It is simply the mean of $(\text{mean}(a,c),b)$ or the mean of $(\text{mean}(a,e),b,c,d)$, etc. Another way you can see this is as the [grand mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_mean) of $(a,c)$ and $(b,b)$ or $(a,e)$, $(b,b)$, $(c,c)$, $(d,d)$.

Answer (score 0):

Both of those are [weighted arithmetic means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean#Mathematical_definition) of the form $\;\displaystyle{\frac {\sum \limits _{i=1}^{n}w_{i}x_{i}}{\sum \limits _{i=1}^{n}w_{i}}}\,$ with $\,w_i \gt 0\,$, for example:

$$
\frac{\cfrac{a}{2} + b + \cfrac{c}{2}}{2} = \frac{\cfrac{1}{2} \cdot a + 1 \cdot b + \cfrac{1}{2} \cdot c}{\cfrac{1}{2} + 1 + \cfrac{1}{2}}
$$

Comment: Interesting, I never thought about it but weighted means are really equivalent to grand means. Neat having a different answer to see this.

Comment: Maybe only in the rational case, actually.

Comment: @ZacharySelk Indeed, and as it happens the [basic example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean#Basic_example) on the wikipedia page is a grand mean.